# How to reverse this equation?

Tags: java, string, encryption, reverse-engineering

The following line of code is inside a `for` loop where `j` is incremented and `ansString` is a string of ASCII characters, like `000\Qg$M!*P000\gQYA+ h000\M|$skd 000\Qo}plsd000\`.

```
ansString[j] = ((char)(paramString[j] >> j % 8 ^ paramString[j]));
```

I am having trouble with figuring out how to have XOR and all the other operators reversed to find `paramString`. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't reverse modulo operation, it'd require to test all the possibilities

Comment: You can reverse this *except* when `(j%8)==0` You should notice that every 8th character of `ansString` is zero, no matter what the input character was.  I think whoever wrote this made a mistake.

Comment: @azro as I am new to this, could you suggest a way I can try to test the possbilities?

Comment: @MattTimmermans interesting, could you explain further why is `(j%8)==0` not reversible?

Comment: When `(j%8)==0`, `ansString[j]==paramString[j]^paramString[j]`, and that comes out to `0`.  All zeros are the same, so there is no way to determine what `paramString[j]` was

Comment: @Raycherr don"t ask the ones who comment how to do. If they know and they want to they will answer, it not : they don"t know ou they don"t want don"t ask them a 2nd time. I my case I don't know how to, just some theory ;)

Answer (score 6):

The right bitshift (>>) and modulo (%) are irreversible operations:

In the case of the right bitshift, underflowed bits are lost, so reversing `a >> b` would leave you with 2^b different possible results.

For the modulo operator, in `x % 8 = y` there are 32 possible values for x asuming it has a maximum length of 8 bits. (That would be every `x * 8 + y` that fit in 8 bits)

The xor operation is the only one reversible. If you have

```
a ^ b = c
```

then

```
c ^ b = a
```

So for more than one input you would have the same output. For example, lets take the case where `j = 0`

```
j % 8 = 0 % 8 = 0

paramString[j] >> (j % 8) = paramString[0] >> 0 = paramString[0]

paramString[0] ^ paramString[j] = paramString[0] ^ paramString[0] = 0
```

This means that for your first character and every 8th subsequent character (this is every character where its index j is a multiple of 8, so `j % 8 = 0`) the result will be 0, whichever the original character was (as you can see in your example output string).

This is why, even if you brute-force every possible input (a total of 256 * n possible input strings, being n the string length), you can never be sure of what was the original input, as many inputs yield the same output.

Comment: Thanks, so to clarify, I will probably have to test (2^b * 32)^n times? where n is the length of ansString

Comment: As your input value can only be 8 bits long, you would only have to test 256 times, but even then you wouldn't be sure of what is the correct output as more than one input will map to the same output.

Answer (score 1):

If `j` is a running index, you will know the shift amount in each iteration. With that, you can find a prefix and decrypt the string.

e.g. for `j = 2` (0..7 are bit positions, double digits are XORed bits, x is 0):

```
Original:   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
Shifted:    x  x  0  1  2  3  4  5
Encrypted:  0  1 02 13 24 35 46 57
```

As you can see, the first 2 digits remain untouched. And those 2 digits are used to encrypt the next two, and so forth.

So to decrypt with j = 2, you find a 2 digit prefix unencrypted. This can be used to decrypt the next 2 bits (02 and 13):

```
Encrypted:  0  1 02 13 24 35 46 57 
Shift-Mask: x  x  0  1  x  x  x  x
Temp1:      0  1  2  3 24 35 46 57
```

Now we know the first 4 digits, and also the decryption bits for the next 2:

```
Temp1:      0  1  2  3 24 35 46 57
Shift-Mask: x  x  x  x  2  3  x  x
Temp2:      0  1  2  3  4  5 46 57
```

And again:

```
Temp2:       0  1  2  3  4  5 46 57
Shift-Mask3: x  x  x  x  x  x  4  5
Decrypted3:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 <- Original string
```

Based on this idea, you can build the decryption algorithm